# Timeout on cucumber-boilerplate

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumberjs

I am trying to run auto testing tool called  [cucumber-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate).
My issue us that I set all what needed but I am getting always

> ```
>      Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
> ```

the code is simple like:

```
  Scenario: login with fake credentials
    Given I open the url "https://test.com"
    When  I log in to site with username "marketionist" and password "1234"
    Then  I expect that element "#js-flash-container .flash-error" is visible
```

Just tried to run simple test like enter url and check title and so on.
Hope  you can help.

Comment: You think, you could also share the test code you are trying to run? Are you calling the `done()` callback?

Comment: I am using the cucumber-boilerplate as it is, you can see all what is running from github. From my test I am using just the templates that already availably for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fount the issue,
You don't need to install pre req, just when you run npm install it will install the chrome drive and selenium ,  also about the timeouts you can change then on config files.